# Connect CosmosDB with Datastax DevCenter Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, azure-cosmosdb, datastax, azure-cosmosdb-cassandra-api

Is this possible to connect CosmosDB Account using Datastax DevCenter Cassandra.

I have created 1 instance of CosmosDB using Cassandra API for this.

As code need Contact Point, port, username & Password: I have these detail added in Devcenter & getting below error:

Detail I have added is correct & as per Azure portal.

[image]

Comment: You'll want to look at this url for more options on connections. I know this url talks about the ability for CQLSH to work with cassandra api of cosmosdb. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/cassandra-support. We used to use the cassandra api of cosmosdb and have since switched to documentdb (SQL) as it's more flexible. The cassandra api is not 100% in line with cassandra, but gives you some of the "feel" of cassandra

Comment: url is correct, I can telnet to that

Answer (score 0):

No, this feature is not supported. I have tried multiple approach but it does not work.